# How download 600k emails from a POP3 server

Tags: linux, server, smtp, backup

How to download all emails (632,000 emails) from a POP server? Currently MacOS Mail limits me to 200,000 emails. Is there a client capable of doing the job without limitation? I do not have access to the server configuration, I am a user.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that quite a collection! Provided there's no way of using IMAP. although i haven't tried to do this myself [thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-GB/) could quite possibly do it, as i don't believe there is a limit along as you don't run out of disk space or RAM, and Attachments will be compressed.